# How to install Orange 2.7 in mac for python scripting

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, orange

I have python 2.7 pre-installed on my mac. I have downloaded the orange snapshot from http://orange.biolab.si/download/. However on opening the python shell in IDLE and typing "import Orange" it gives error "no such module exists".

Further upon trying to do the easy_install by typing on Terminal "easy_install numpy && easy_install orange", I get the following error. Am I missing something elementary here? Look forward to inputs.

```
Searching for numpy
Best match: numpy 1.7.1
Adding numpy 1.7.1 to easy-install.pth file
Using /Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for numpy
Finished processing dependencies for numpy
Searching for orange
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/orange/
Reading http://orange.biolab.si
Reading http://orange.biolab.si/svn/orange/trunk
Reading http://orange.biolab.si/
Reading https://bitbucket.org/biolab/orange/downloads
Best match: Orange 2.7
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/O/Orange/Orange-2.7.tar.gz#md5=74f8fdb45688ef75ced7838567846470
Processing Orange-2.7.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/h5/z1wnbzk518j1vvgzt9x2m9j40000gn/T/easy_install-zJCDvj/Orange-2.7/setup.cfg
Running Orange-2.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/h5/z1wnbzk518j1vvgzt9x2m9j40000gn/T/easy_install-zJCDvj/Orange-2.7/egg-dist-tmp-Zb7l0Q
Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
Make sure that Python modules _winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'source/orangeqt/build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'source/orange/px'
no previously-included directories found matching 'source/orange/ppp'
no previously-included directories found matching 'source/orangeom/px'
no previously-included directories found matching 'source/orangene/ppp'
no previously-included directories found matching 'source/orangene/px'
no previously-included directories found matching 'source/orangene/ppp'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'source/orangeom/lib_vectors.cpp'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'source/orangene/lib_vectors.cpp'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/bin/easy_install", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1954, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1935, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1958, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 358, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 602, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 632, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 827, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1107, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1093, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 33, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 81, in run
    return func()
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 35, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 792, in <module>
  File "setup.py", line 788, in setup_package
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 179, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 166, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 454, in run
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 92, in run
    self.build()
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 111, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 309, in run
    customize_compiler(self.compiler)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 170, in customize_compiler
    _osx_support.customize_compiler(_config_vars)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 412, in customize_compiler
    _find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)
  File "/Users/Sunny/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler
    "Cannot locate working compiler")
SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler
```